# Is there a Visual Studio start page open event that a Visual Studio Extension can subscribe to?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm working on a Visual Studio extension which would benefit from being loaded when the IDE's start page is opened, but I cannot find an event that is fired when the start page is opened that my extension can subscribe to.

I know I can add the following attribute to my vsix package that will fire when the IDE is opened, but I am looking for something more specific to the start page itself.

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]
```

Is there an event that is fired when either the default start page or a custom the start page is opened ?

Comment: Given that the user can opt out of having any start page, I think it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working in the end by subscribing to the WindowVisibilityEvents (courtesy of this old post from Carlos Quintero https://www.mztools.com/articles/2011/MZ2011010.aspx) and checking the window's type and title when it became visible.

The following is a cut-down version of the code in my vsix package class:

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        IServiceContainer serviceContainer = this as IServiceContainer;
        EnvDTE.DTE dte = serviceContainer.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
        var events2 = (EnvDTE80.Events2)dte.Events;
        EnvDTE80.WindowVisibilityEvents toolBoxWindowVisibilityEvents = events2.get_WindowVisibilityEvents();
        toolBoxWindowVisibilityEvents.WindowShowing += WindowVisibilityEvents_WindowShowing;
    }

    private void WindowVisibilityEvents_WindowShowing(Window window)
    {
        if (window.Type == vsWindowType.vsWindowTypeToolWindow && window.Caption == "Start Page")
        {
            //Start page is opening...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to DTE.Events.[WindowEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dispwindowevents_event?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).**WindowCreated** event and check that the window title is **Start Page**.

Comment: I tried this but was unsuccessful - this may have been down to me but since I discovered an alternative solution (see my own answer below) I didn't pursue this.